# Syntax - Adding html attributes to Drop down categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to PHP and Wordpress. I have the following code in one of my plugin file. It is used to generate a drop down for categories. I want to add an html attribute to it. I want to add the html attribute "autofocus" to it so that when the page load this select box has focus by default.

```
<?php  

    wp_dropdown_categories( array( 

        'name'          => 'question-category',

        'id'            => 'question-category',

        'taxonomy'      => 'dwqa-question_category',

        'show_option_none' => __('Select a question category','dwqa'),

        'hide_empty'    => 0,

        'quicktags'     => array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,spell,close' ),            

    ) );

?>
```

I am having problem with the syntax in which this should be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your best bet is going to be to set the `echo` attribute to `false` and then find and replace parts of the html that is returned.

```
<?php  

    $questioncategory = wp_dropdown_categories( array( 

        'echo'     => false,

        'name'          => 'question-category',

        'id'            => 'question-category',

        'taxonomy'      => 'dwqa-question_category',

        'show_option_none' => __('Select a question category','dwqa'),

        'hide_empty'    => 0,

        'quicktags'     => array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,spell,close' ),            

    ) );

    $questioncategory = str_replace('<select', '<select autofocus', $questioncategory);
    echo $questioncategory;

?>
```

Comment: worked for me!! only change I had to remove the "-" you had mentioned in your variable. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

try adding this:

```
'autofocus'     => 'autofocus'
```

So

```
<?php  

    wp_dropdown_categories( array( 

        'autofocus'     => 'autofocus',

        'name'          => 'question-category',

        'id'            => 'question-category',

        'taxonomy'      => 'dwqa-question_category',

        'show_option_none' => __('Select a question category','dwqa'),

        'hide_empty'    => 0,

        'quicktags'     => array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,spell,close' ),            

    ) );

?>
```